# Can't get dumpio on Apache 2.4 Oracle Linux 8.6 php 8

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, log-files

I can't get **dumpio** to log POST request data.

**httpd.conf:**

```
...
Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf
...
```

No LogLevel or dumpio related stuff in there.

**httpd-le-ssl.conf:**

```
<virtualHost *:443>
    ...
    <IfModule dumpio_module>
        ErrorLog "logs/dumpio_log"
        <IfModule log_config_module>
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        </IfModule>    
        DumpIOInput On
        DumpIOOutput On
        LogLevel dumpio:trace7
    </IfModule>
</virtualHost>
```

(I'm not dealing with HTTP on port 80, everything 301-redirected to 443)

**I did:**

`setenforce Permissive`
(in case SElinux is hindering something)

`apachectl configtest`
(Syntax ok)

`apachectl restart`

`httpd —M |grep -E "dumpio|log_config"` (both loaded)

Now, when submitting a **POST** using a `<form methode="POST">`, the only thing that's logged:

**/var/log/httpd/access_log:**

```
<ip> - - [<date time>] "POST /form.php HTTP/2.0" 200 - "<server url>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

but no detailed data. Specifically, there is nothing related in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` nor in any `logs/dumpio_log`. The latter file is created but contains 0 bytes.

What am I missing?

Comment: you should be looking at the error_log defined in your virtualhost I believe.

Comment: I've checked all logs. I read it should be in there, but it's not. Meanwhile, as a workarround, I've installed mod_security. That write tons of data incl. POST values to /var/log/httpd/modsec_audit.log . But I'd rather get dumpio to work.

Answer (score 1):

mod_dumpio directives are only valid in server config context, not virtualhost like in your example.

Described in here in "Context" under the description of each directive:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html

Comment: I put the block dumpio_module block at the end of my httpd.conf and deleted it from the virtualHost. Restartet Apache. httpd -M shows dumpio is loaded. But no change. dumpio_log got created but only contains messages from the Apache restart. - Meanwhile I am using mod_security to protocol everything and use a tail pipe with sed to extract the form post data that I need. I'd rather have dumpio running.

Answer (score 0):

Two other things, besides [Daniel's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1112245/304183) which rightly said it must be turned on at the server context, not vhost context, which I needed to do to get `mod_dumpio` working:

1. Check that no other LogLevels are overriding `LogLevel dumpio:trace7`. Places to check are within includes (like Certbot's) and also Apache's (in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`) logs/ssl_error_log, where there might be a `LogLevel warn` that needs to be commented out.
2. Check that you're looking at the right log file- the Apache ssl conf file in my case caused mod_dumpio to log to `/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log` instead of `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.